# StackDriver - Simple Log alerts for more than X lines matched per 1minute

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Very simple scenario StackDriver logging alert scenario. Alert me if there are more than 100 404s log entries in the nginx log in a 1 minute period. I've setup the log filter and this works correctly, filtering 404 lines.

And I can almost get the graph to show this in dashboard, and I guess the minor difference here is in the sampling and minute boundaries, that's ok, good enough.

But defining a policy I can't figure out how to specify this, as the policy graph is back to 0.x/sec, one can't specify sampling period or aggregation here.

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Stackdriver team. Currently, you will need to set your alert threshold on a per-second rate (1.6/s in your case). Alerting on the number of events over a period is a feature that is coming soon in Stackdriver. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sraj, I look forward to the new feature. The workaround I havent found reliable I guess it could be down to samples not arriving at the exact intervals etc.. What is the ETA on this new feature? Is there a roadmap anywhere? Thanks. Love to know how many people are on the StackDriver team? Are the original devs still with you after the GCloud acquision?